# Xcode how to dismiss keyboard on background touch with UIScroll

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

This is driving me insane.  Figured out how to dismiss the keyboard on a scroll but cannot get the tap to work.

In my .h;

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberTextField;
```

In the .m

```
   - (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
        [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];

    }
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Linked the backgroundTap to the UIControl does not work. As stated above the scrollViewWillBeginDragging does work.  How can I get the backgroundTap to work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain backgroundTap method is being called? Is it attached to a UIView that has User Interaction Enabled ticked?

You can also use...

```
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
```

...which will work for multiple text fields, so that you don't have to figure out which text field is the first responder and specify exactly which one it is that you want to resign.

Comment: Here is a screen shot of it; http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m99kngCafz1rpy3i5o1_400.png.  I did add the code you listed and it did not make a difference

Comment: What is your view heirarchy? Where is this UIControl in relation to the UIScrollView? UIScrollView might be swallowing your touch events.